Есть ли в wpf xaml c# что-то наподобие innerHTML из js?
Я делаю программу в которой пользователь сам создаëт xaml окно, и оно отображается у меня в StackPanel. Как мне такое реализовать? MainWindow.MyStackPanel.innerXAML = File.ReadAllText("user xaml file.xaml");//нужно типо такогоили типо такого:MyStackPanel.AddChild("текст xaml кодировки");(я знаю что есть добавление дочерних объектов, но не с xaml кодировки а так:Button btn = new Button(); MyStackPanel.Children.Add(btn);)

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

смотрите в сторону System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader

ссылка на документацию с примером
